# stackdriver-monitoring-agent spams logs on Containers on Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-compute-engine

I installed a web application on [Containers on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers), which intially seemed to work fine. However, the web application crashes after a few days, to an extent where I can not even ssh into the VM anymore. Resetting the VM brings everything back to normal. By looking into the VM while it was still running, I found that the log file belonging to
`gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-monitoring-agent:0.2-5.5.2-379`  in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<container-id>/<container-id>.json.log` is growing evermore in size and is likely filling up the disk. The logs look like

```
{"log":"fc_process_chain (chain = PostCache);\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190876557Z"}
{"log":"fc_process_chain (PostCache): Testing the `processes' rule.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190886798Z"}
{"log":"regex match: Regular expression `^processes$' does not match `docker.interface'.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190891606Z"}
{"log":"fc_process_chain (PostCache): Testing the `otherwise' rule.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190896668Z"}
{"log":"fc_process_chain (PostCache): Rule `otherwise' matches.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190901529Z"}
{"log":"plugin: plugin_write: Writing values via write_gcm.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190906438Z"}
{"log":"fc_process_chain (PostCache): Executing the default targets.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190911762Z"}
{"log":"fc_process_chain (PostCache): Signaling `continue' at end of chain.\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190916501Z"}
{"log":"plugin_dispatch_values: time = 1649917767.189; interval = 60.000; host = container.95581b3acde1a56ad0eba183ea510aa99f24c87f26b709378395bcdae2cf39e8; plugin = docker.interface; plugin_instance = eth0; type = if_packets; type_instance = ;\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2022-04-14T06:29:27.190921452Z"}
```

So I would like to know whether I need to do something, so these logs can be flushed or limited in size.

My terrafrom config to deploy looks like

```
module "gce-container" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/container-vm/google"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  cos_image_name = var.cos_image_name

  container = {
    image = "docker.io/myimage"

  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "this" {
  project      = var.project_id
  name         = local.name
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone         = var.zone

  tags = [local.name]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = module.gce-container.source_image
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.network.network_id

    access_config {
      nat_ip = module.address.addresses[0]
    }
  }

  metadata = {
    gce-container-declaration = module.gce-container.metadata_value
    google-logging-enabled    = "true"
    google-monitoring-enabled = "true"
  }

  labels = {
    container-vm = module.gce-container.vm_container_label
  }

  service_account {
    email  = google_service_account.this.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of logrotation or software like log4j? How many logs it generates by day?

Comment: I don't think so, the container I am running is https://github.com/drakkan/sftpgo . I see that a ton of logs are generated every second, but to me it does not seem that the logs are coming from the application, but rather from the monitoring agent.